# Calling an M tag from .NET using Cache'

Tags: .net, excel, intersystems-cache, mumps, vba

I'm trying to find a way to call a MUMPS tag ideally from VBA, but alternatively from .NET. I know that you can do "sql" commands using Intersystems' provided APIs, but how can I just do something like `d ^MYROUTINE`?

Comment: `from .NET (ideally from VBA)` - VBA is not .NET.  Maybe you mean VB.NET?

Comment: @Tim: Yes I understand. I edited the question to make this more clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to call a routine directly from Bindings.

The most natural way to do this would be to make a class wrapper - AKA a class that has a ClassMethod that calls `^MYROUTINE`. Then, generate .NET Proxy Classes and call the ClassMethod from .NET.

If you are doing new development, use .NET if all possible - it will have the best support on all fronts moving forward.

Answer (score 1):

Might it make sense to wrap your method in a ClassMethod and then declare your method as a [SQLProc].  If you already are doing "sql" commands this might be a natural fit.

Answer (score 1):

Install Vism control on your machine

Add Vism Components in your Dotnet Project Using "Project->Companents" Option

Use this line:

VisM1.NameSpace="@MyNS"
 VisM1.Server="CN_IPTCP:server[port]:username:password"

Then Vism1.Execute (Here ur code)